# Cumulative Conditional Probability Function of First Jump of Poisson Process Occurring Before Others

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

What is the cumulative conditional probability in $(0,T)$ (i.e. $0<\tau<T$) that the first arrival of a Poisson process event of intensity $\lambda_1$ occurs before first-arrivals of all other Poisson processes $\lambda_2$, $\lambda_3$,...,$\lambda_n$

The unconditional cumulative probability function of the first arrival is then given by

$P(\tau_1<T) = (1-e^{(-\lambda_1 T)})$

For its conditional counterpart then, it feels like the below is a step in the right direction (probability of occurance of $\tau_1$ conditional on joint prob of no occurrance of $\tau_{j\neq1}$) but a more lucid & complete/correct derivation would be great

$P(\tau_1<T|\tau_1<\tau_j, \forall  j=2,...,n) = \frac{(1-e^{(-\lambda_1 T)})}{e^{(-\lambda_2 T)}e^{(-\lambda_3 T)}...e^{(-\lambda_n T)}} = \frac{(1-e^{(-\lambda_1 T)}}{\prod\limits_{j=2}^n e^{(-\lambda_j T)}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\tau=\min\limits_i\tau_i$ and $\nu$ the random variable such that $[\nu=i]=[\tau=\tau_i]$ for each $i$. Then $(\tau,\nu)$ is independent, $\tau$ is exponential with parameter $\lambda=\sum\limits_{i}\lambda_i$ and, for every $i$, $[\nu=i]$ has probability $\lambda_i/\lambda$. Since $[\nu=i]=[\forall j\ne i,\tau_j\gt\tau_i]$, one gets:

> The conditional distribution of $\tau_i$ conditionally on the event $[\forall j\ne i,\tau_j\gt\tau_i]$ is exponential with parameter $\lambda$. In particular, this conditional distribution does not depend on $i$.

The easiest way to check the independence of $(\tau,\nu)$ asserted above might be to compute, for every $t$ and $i$,
$$
P(\tau\gt t,\nu=i)=P(\tau_i\gt t,\forall j\ne i,\tau_j\gt\tau_i).
$$
For every $s$,
$$
P(\forall j\ne i,\tau_j\gt s)=\prod_{j\ne i}P(\tau_j\gt s)=\prod_{j\ne i}\mathrm e^{-\lambda_js}=\mathrm e^{-(\lambda-\lambda_i)s},
$$
hence
$$
P(\forall j\ne i,\tau_j\gt\tau_i\mid\tau_i)=\mathrm e^{-(\lambda-\lambda_i)\tau_i}.
$$
Conditioning on $\tau_i$, this implies
$$
P(\tau\gt t,\nu=i)=\int_t^\infty\lambda_i\mathrm e^{-\lambda_is}\mathrm e^{-(\lambda-\lambda_i)s}\mathrm ds=(\lambda_i/\lambda)\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}.
$$
This last identity is enough to identify the distributions of $\tau$ and $\nu$ and to check that $(\tau,\nu)$ is indeed independent.

**Edit:** For every $t\geqslant0$ and every $i$,
$$
P(\tau_i\leqslant t\mid\forall j\ne i,\tau_j\gt\tau_i)=1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}.
$$

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: $P(\tau_1 <= t|\forall i \neq 1, \tau_i > \tau_1 ) = 1 - e^{-\lambda t}$ Here is $\lambda = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$?

Comment: Please read. $ $

Comment: Hi Did, I did read of course, thank you. Just looking for clarification on $\lambda= \sum\limits_{i} \lambda_i$ as you wrote it (and as it appears in the final P() expression). Is this for i = 2,...,n in the summation? Would you mind terribly expanding this for my understanding. Much Appreciated

Comment: Yes $\lambda$ is the sum of all the $\lambda_i$ available, thus $\lambda=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\lambda_i$. Likewise, $\prod\limits_{j\ne i}$ has the obvious meaning.

Comment: Would this not mean then for example that $1-e^{-\lambda t} =  1-e^{-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i} = P(\tau_1 < t| \forall i \neq 1, \tau_i > \tau_1) = P(\tau_2 < t| \forall i \neq 2, \tau_i > \tau_2)$ even if all the processes have different $\lambda_i$ values? We should be seeing a different conditional probability for each $\tau_i$ having a different $\lambda_i$

Comment: Yes this is what the result means. Why should we see a different conditional probability for each $\tau_i$ when the $\lambda_i$ are different? Let me suggest that you try to solve completely the case $n=2$, to check that indeed $P(\tau_1\lt t\mid\tau_1\lt\tau_2)=P(\tau_2\lt t\mid\tau_2\lt\tau_1)$.

Comment: its a good suggestion, thanks for your help